# I want to apply visa as I m crew

Tags: visas

I m working as crew so I want to apply for tourist visa so which document I have to submit as a tourist. I am flying everyday so how many days it will take for passport  ?

Comment: What country do you want a visa for? And what passport do you have?

Comment: Many countries have a provision to allow citizens to have more than one passport if they frequently need to travel while applying for visas. As a crew member, you could well qualify if you need your passport every day and can't leave it behind at a consulate to apply for a visa. If you tell us what passport you have, we can look up the relevant rules for you.